# How to automatically envoke context factory inside view tests with urldispatch

Tags: python, testing, pyramid

I have an existing Pyramid application that makes use of url dispatch. It has urls of the form '/kind1/{id1}/kind2/{id2}.../action'. So traversal sould have been ideal but it wasn't used.

In each view there is a function call that fetches the instance from the url. Eg there might be a call like `thingy_instance = get_thingy_from_url(request)`

Now I needed to add permissions to the views. So I added context factories to the route configuration stuff. Something like: `config.add_route('thingy_action','/kind1/{id1}/kind2/{id2}.../action', factory='ThingyContext')`

Now it would make sense for ThingyContext to fetch the thing, so that in the view itself I can do stuff like `thingy_instance = request.context.thingy_instance`, instead of `thingy_instance = get_thingy_from_url(request)`

This so far is pretty straight forward and doable. But it breaks all the unit tests that directly test the views because the request context doesn't get filled in.

eg, a test like so:

```
def test_thingy_action_scenario(self):
    stuff...
    x = thingy_action(request)
```

would give me an exception like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/waxed_backend/waxed_backend/concerns/accountable_basics/tests/view_tests.py", line 72, in test_alles
    self.assertRaises(UserNotFound,lambda:get_user(request))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 473, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/waxed_backend/waxed_backend/concerns/accountable_basics/tests/view_tests.py", line 72, in <lambda>
    self.assertRaises(UserNotFound,lambda:get_user(request))
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/waxed_backend/waxed_backend/concerns/accountable_basics/views.py", line 69, in get_user
    oUser = request.context.oUser
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thingy_instance'
```

In short. In the tests `request.context` is None. But when accessing the views via their urls it all works fine.

eg: this kind of thing works with the new set up `curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://stuff/kind1/{id1}/kind2/{id2}.../action/'`

So what's a graceful way of dealing with this? I want to use the context inside the view, and have the tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a functional test instead of a unit test. In Pyramid the views themselves are "just functions" and do not do anything to fill in the context etc. They are called by Pyramid's router after all these other things have happened. But you aren't using the router in these tests so none of those things are happening.

If you want to just test the view function itself in a unit test then you could have your test set `request.context = ThingyContext(...)` and your view should be happy.

If you want to test things more like how a client like curl would test it, you want to use webtest.

```
from webtest import TestApp

app = config.make_wsgi_app()
testapp = TestApp(app)
response = testapp.get('/')
```

This will require a full application, not just the view function.

Comment: If I was writing the tests from scratch then I would do it this way. But I am working on a project with a huuuge number of tests already in place. I want to minimise rewrite as much as possible

Comment: The only other option was also in my answer... `request.context = ...` in your test. Not sure what else you need here to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I would have to copy-paste a lot of code to a lot of tests then... so that's not so nice either

Comment: That's what fixtures are for. I'm sorry there isn't a more satisfactory answer for you.